# Tensorflow: how to create feature_columns for numpy matrix input

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow 1.8.0, python 3.6.5. 
The data is iris data set. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

X = iris['data']
y = iris['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

input_train=tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x=X_train,
            y=y_train, num_epochs=100, shuffle=False)
classifier_model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 
                  20, 10], n_classes=3, feature_columns=??)
```

Here is my problem, how do I setup the feature_columns for a numpy matrix?

If I covert the X and y to `pandas.DataFrame`, I can use the following code for the feature_columns, and it works in the `DNNClassifier` model.

```
features = X.columns
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key) for key in features]
```

Comment: These links might be of use:[tf.feature_column docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/) and  [tf.estimator.DNNClassifier docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier#top_of_page)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your numpy ndarray in a dictionary and pass it to `numpy_input_fn` method as input `x` and then use the key in that dictionary to define your `feature_column`. Also note that because each data in your `X_train` has 4 dimensions, you need to specify the `shape` parameter when defining `tf.feature_column.numeric_column`. Here is the completed code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

iris = load_iris()

X = iris['data']
y = iris['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

input_train = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
                  x = {'x': X_train},
                  y = y_train,
                  num_epochs = 100,
                  shuffle = False)

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='x', shape=(X_train.shape[1],))]

classifier_model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
                       hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                       n_classes=3,
                       feature_columns=feature_columns)
```

Comment: This isn't working, here's an error I'm getting: "Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v2.estimator' has no attribute 'inputs'"

Comment: @aokelly This is because you are using tensorflow 2.x. This question and my answer are based on tensorflow 1.8.0.