# Tensorflow 2.0: how to create feature_columns for numpy matrix input

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I understand how to do this in Tensorflow 1.x ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51108765/tensorflow-how-to-create-feature-columns-for-numpy-matrix-input))

But for Tensorflow 2.0, how to create feature_columns for numpy matrix?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

X = iris['data']
y = iris['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
ds_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))

model = CustomModel(feature_columns, num_classes=y_train.shape[1])
model.compile()
model.compile('adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics='accuracy')
```

According to the docstring of the CustomModel, it asks for `feature_columns: The Tensorflow feature columns for the dataset.`

I used iris dataset from sklearn as an example. I understand that tensorflow2.0 has an iris dataset. If I use that dataset, I won't have this problem. But that's not the point. I'd like to know how to create feature columns to feed into the tensorflow model, given I've had numpy matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The TensorFlow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns) has all the examples we usually need. If you want to create Boosted tree models there is another [article](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/03/how-to-train-boosted-trees-models-in-tensorflow.html)

I use this dataset just to show how Pandas dataframe is used to create tf.data

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

seaflow_train = pd.read_csv(
    "~/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow2/seaflow_21min.csv")

print(seaflow_train.head())
print(seaflow_train.columns)
seaflow_train['target'] = seaflow_train['pop']

seaflow_train = seaflow_train.drop(columns=['file_id', 'cell_id', 'time', 'd1', 'd2'])

train, test = train_test_split(seaflow_train, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)

# A utility method to create a tf.data dataset from a Pandas Dataframe
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  dataframe = dataframe.copy()
  labels = dataframe.pop('target')
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  return ds

batch_size = 5 # A small batch sized is used for demonstration purposes
train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
```